# how to use chinese character in pymysql to create table?

Tags: cjk, pymysql

1.sqlite3

```
import sqlite3
con=sqlite3.connect("g:\\mytest1.db")
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute('create  table test (上市  TEXT)')
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```

I  successfully create a test table mytest1.db ,and a chinese character name "上市"  as field.

2.in mysql command console.

```
C:\Users\root>mysql -uroot -p   
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.  
mysql> create database mytest2;  
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)  
mysql> use mytest2;  
Database changed  
mysql> set names "gb2312";  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)  
mysql> create table  stock(上市 TEXT) ;  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)
```

The conclusion can be get : chinese characters  can be used in mysql console.

3.pymysql

code31

```
import pymysql
con = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='******')
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("create database  if not exists mytest31")
cur.execute("use mytest31")
cur.execute('set names "gb2312" ')
cur.execute('create table  stock(上市 TEXT) ')
con.commit()
```

code32

```
import pymysql
con = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='******')
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("create database  if not exists mytest32")
cur.execute("use mytest32")
cur.execute('set names "gb2312" ')
cur.execute('create table  stock(上市  TEXT) ')
con.commit()
```

The same problem occurs

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 21-22: o rdinal not in range(256)
```

4.mysql-python-connect

code 41

```
import mysql.connector  
config={'host':'127.0.0.1', 
        'user':'root',  
        'password':'123456',  
        'port':3306 , 
        'charset':'utf8' 
        }  

con=mysql.connector.connect(**config) 
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("create database  if not exists mytest41")
cur.execute("use mytest41")
cur.execute('set names "gb2312" ')
str='create table  stock(上市  TEXT)'
cur.execute(str)
```

code 42

```
import mysql.connector  
config={'host':'127.0.0.1', 
        'user':'root',  
        'password':'******',  
        'port':3306 , 
        'charset':'utf8' 
        }  

con=mysql.connector.connect(**config) 
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute("create database  if not exists mytest42")
cur.execute("use mytest42")
cur.execute('set names "gb2312" ')
str='create table  stock(上市.encode("utf-8") TEXT)'
cur.execute(str)
```

same errrors such as in pymysql.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 22-23: o
rdinal not in range(256)
```

It is surely a bug in python mysql module that chinese characters can not be used as field name.
1.Chinese characters can  be used as field name  in python sqlite3 module.
2.Chinese characters can  be used as field name  in mysql console only if you 'set name "gb2312" '

Comment: The main question is, why do you want Chinese (or other non-ASCII) characters to be the table name? Can't use English names as table name?

Comment: I want to make the field in the table to be chinese character,not table name.

Comment: I can do that in python module-- sqlite3,maybe there is a bug in pymysql.

Comment: Advice: do NOT use Chinese characters in field names, or table names.

Comment: set_charset(“utf8mb4”);. should be working here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pymysql.connect()` [accepts a charset argument](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L518). I have tested `charset="utf8"` and `charset="gb2312"` and both works (Python 3, PyMySQL 0.6.2). You don't need to use a `"SET NAMES"` query in this case.

```
import pymysql
con = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306,
                      user='root', passwd='******',
                      charset="utf8")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create database if not exists mytest31")
cur.execute("use mytest31")
cur.execute("create table stock(上市 TEXT)")
con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're `encode`ing when you should `decode`.  To convert a Chinese character to a unicode character, use:

```
"上市".decode("GB18030")
```

Which is an encoding generally used for Chinese chars.  `latin-1` will not work as most Chinese characters are not within its scope.  The `GB18030` encoding *should* work, but if not, there are a host of other encodings you can try, like `gbk` or `big5_hkscs` (generally for encodings done within HK/China).

Unicode errors are easy to spot, they show up as `u'\ufffd'` (which when encoded will be a diamond with a question mark in the middle).

I hope this was helpful!

**Edit:**  I'm somewhat confused by your comment.

```
>>> print type("上市")
<type 'str'>
>>> print type("上市".decode("GB18030"))
<type 'unicode'>
```

`str.decode()` returns unicode.

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode',your method isn't the right way ,in python all string is unicode,unicode can not decode,it can only be encoded.

Comment: please try it in python3.3,>>> print(type("上市".decode("GB18030")))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Ahh, well that's the problem. I wish I'd had that info. The other answer appears to have it though.